# Label Direction

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a Grid with GridTemplateColumn that contains Label.
the grid direction set to rtl and I want the lable's direction to be ltr.
how can I do that ?

I tried:

```
<asp:Label style="direction:ltr" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"/>
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create a CSS class such as

```
.lbl_ltr
{
  direction:ltr;
}
```

and then

```
<asp:Label CssClass="lbl_ltr" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="Foo" runat="server" dir="rtl" Text="Hello World!" />
```

Will dir="rtl" do the thing? See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twe16yc2.aspx

Comment: this is very useful for other languages.for example in some country you type 02/05/1988 ,also in other country such as mine people type 1366/02/05.in this case it's important!